# Symfony 2 - Best practice to upload an image on Amazon S3

Tags: php, upload, amazon-s3, symfony-2.1

I have a form in which I have a `file` field to upload an image. I need to upload this image on Amazon S3. Building this step by step I started to upload the image on the local disk and it's now working.

The upload is occurring inside my entity `Page` as it's recommended to test the success of the upload before to save the entity. I ended up with this chunk of code

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="objectThumbnail", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $objectThumbnail;

    /**
     * This is not a column in the database but it's mapping a field from the form
     *
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="600000000")
     */
    public $file;

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            // generate a unique filename
            $this->objectThumbnail = $this->getGuid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
        // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
        // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->objectThumbnail);

        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
```

That's perfect, it's working like a charm.
Just Symfony (2.1.7) screaming because of the public scope of the `file` attribute, nothing major.

Now I need to integrate the S3 layer. For that I think I'll be using `Gaufrette` and `StreamWrapper`.

Now I'm struggling to find what is the best way to do it. How do I get access to the `Filesystem` service in the Entity? Is it really clean to do it like this? It feels a bit awkward to me to process the upload of the image on S3 in the Entity.

How would you recommend to do it ?

Cheers,

Maxime

Comment: Hi @maxwell2022, which approach did you take to solve this problem ? Did you use Gaufrette bundle or Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle ? Tks for your good question...

Comment: Yes, I used Gaufrette. Read the comments of the accepted answer, there is more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using service in your entity is not a good pratice.
I would recommand to create a form handler that performs validation, persistance and upload in this example

i wrote an example that fits your needs

```
//...
//inside a creation controller action
//...
//create a new page entity
$page = new Page();

//get your page form class
$form = $this->createForm(new PageForm(), $page);

//call your form handler
$formHandler = new PageFormHandler(
        $form,
        $this->get('request'),
        $this->get('your.gaufrette.filesystem'),
        $this->get('your.page.manager')
);

//form is valid ?
if ($formHandler->process()) {         
    //flash message, redirection etc
}
```

The handler class

```
namespace YourCompagnyBundle\Form\Handler;

use YourCompagnyBundle\Entity\Page;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Gaufrette\Filesystem;


class PageFormHandler
{
    protected $form;
    protected $request;
    protected $pageManager;
    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, Filesystem $filesystem, $pageManager)
    {
        $this->form    = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->pageManager = $pageManager;
    }

    public function process()
    {
        if( $this->request->getMethod() == 'POST' )
        {
            $this->form->bind($this->request);

            if( $this->form->isValid() )
            {
               $this->onSuccess($this->form->getData());               

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    function onSuccess(Page $page)
    {
        //has uploaded file ?
        if($page->getFile() instanceof UploadedFile){
            //do some logic with gaufrette filesystem
           //if page is already managed in database (update), delete previous file


        }
        //storage
        $this->pageManager->save($page);
    }

}
```

Hope this helped

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when you delete the `Page` entity it's not deleting the image on S3. Whereas having the `@ORM\PostRemove()` in the `Page` entity would handle this case. I thought about this but I'd like to find a solution that would handle all cases (insert, update and delete) the best way possible. thx

Comment: i have put this example for creation. In my case the pageManager class is a service layer that persists/delete your entity, manage events, etc. Deletion would be another form, but in both, events are still dispatched by the entity manager.

Comment: note that update is the tricky case because you have to detect a new file upload, delete previous file and saving new one

Comment: so you have a `PageManager` that is a custom `EntityManager` for your `Page` entity. But I don't know what you are using it for because you save the image in `onSuccess` before to save the `Page`. I have 2 questions: What if there is an exception saving your `Page` knowing you've uploaded the image already? Would it be a better idea to inject the `Filesystem` object in the `PageManager` and do the upload on `save()`, delete on `delete()`?

Comment: the pagemanager is a service where i inject my entity manager, logger, etc.  There are save/update/delete methods where i can do my logic. You can use a try .. catch structure in these method if you dont want the exception to propagate to the controller.  In my example in put the filesystem in the formHandler:onSuccess, but you can inject the filesystem in your pageManager and use it the save method. As you prefer.

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about the logger but it's a good idea ;)
I think it make more sense to have the image saved and delete in the `PageManager` as it's really tight with the entity (the image can't exist without `Page` entity). I'll give a try this weekend and I'll let you know how I go.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should check [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) which basically inject File object into your entites and integration with Gaufrette is quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks great but I prefer to handle it in my bundle. I find it easier to understand and debug